# Redirect page to homepage, keeping URL

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, template-include

I'm creating a site where every page is really rendered on a single page - the homepage. I'd like to make it so page URLs - like `/about-us/` - redirect back to the homepage, but keep the same URL (`/`). For example, if I visit `http://example.com/about-us/`, I want to see `http://example.com/` (scrolled down to the correct section, thanks to some JS), but with the URL still as `http://example.com/about-us/`.

The `template_include` action seems like it'd work, but doing this:

```
function home_template($template) {
  return locate_template(array('index.php'));
}
add_action('template_include', 'home_template');
```

causes a full redirect to the homepage for some reason (URL and all). Not sure why. Moving the homepage template to `home.php` or `front_page.php` (and update the above code accordingly) doesn't fix the issue.

`add_rewrite_rule` also seemed promising, but it also seems to simply redirect to the homepage, at least with the following code:

```
function home_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule('about-us', 'index.php', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'home_rewrite');
```

`wp_redirect` also doesn't do what I'm looking for.

Any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: That actually sounds like a good candidate for a frontend JS framework like Vue.js, it would be far easier, and faster for the end user to look into something like that rather than forcing WordPress to do that.

Comment: Yeah I could maybe do this with Express.JS and use WordPress as a headless CMS, but if this is possible to do with just WordPress I'd really prefer that for this project.